# Dynamic initialisation of a Javascript class

Tags: javascript

How can I call a javascript class from a string? Is that possible at all? One solution I didn't find that good was to store the initialization of the classes in an array and then address the object via the key. But are there other possibilities?

**What I want**

```js
const classNameAsString = "HelloWorld";

class HelloWorld {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Hello World")
  }
}

const hW = new ${classNameAsString}(); // that is wrong and would throw an error
```

Comment: have you looked into `eval`?

Comment: What do you mean by "call a `class`"? A `class` isn't a function...

Comment: @Dai (yeah they are) - `typeof (class Example{})`

Comment: @evolutionxbox A class constructor is a `function`, and a `class` is sugar over a `function` too, but that's not the same thing as having `class` function objects being functors...

Comment: You can store the class in an object and use bracket notation

Comment: @IłyaBursov I dont use eval! But thank you for your comment!

Comment: @Dai I edit. I mean initialisation. Thanks for sugesstion

Comment: Did the OP already try any global scope? e.g. for the global `window` scope ... `const hW = new window[classNameAsString]();`. In environments with e.g. module scope (but not only there) the OP is free of importing class-constructors and assign it to an e.g. `classes` object which then could be accessed and instantiated like `const hW = new classes[classNameAsString]();`

Comment: @Xion14 You are right! I already read that in stackoverflow. But i will know if exists other solution to do this. But thank you for your good sugesstion!

Comment: @PeterSeliger Your comment sounds very good! Unfortnatly the question was close because your idea would be a good answer.

Comment: @MaikLowrey ... my comment is as good an answer as it was without the closed thread.

Comment: The linked question [has a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5187620/989920)

Comment: @PeterSeliger hmm, you are right ;-)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Merci for the link! I will try. The only problem would be that i didnt want use the class in the global scope because it is only a helperClass which i will use in a VueJs app.